# Wait for a docker container to be ready with command in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, startup

I have a mysql-db and prisma image in my docker-compose.yml. I want prisma to wait for the db to be ready, cause otherwise prisma keeps restarting and it wont work at all. And I know from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), that I can use [./wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) but I was not able to connect the pieces after searching for a while.

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.25
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
    - "4001:4466"
    depends_on:
    - db

    # I added this command
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:33061", "--"] 

    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        managementApiSecret: server.secret.123
        port: 4466
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mysql
            active: true
            host: db
            port: 3306
            user: ***
            password: ***
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ***
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ***
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"
    volumes:
      - /docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

I added the command above but nothing changed, not even an error in the logs but as I understand, the command is run inside the container.

1. **How do I get the ./wait-for-it.sh into the container?**
2. **And can this even work this way with the command or does this depend
   on the prisma-image?**
3. **Otherwise, how would I achieve the waiting?**

I just have the docker-compose file and want to do `docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found out how to include `wait-for-it.sh` into the container.

I downloaded the wait-for-it.sh into the project folder and then I created a file called **Dockerfile** with the contents:

```
FROM prismagraphql/prisma:1.25
COPY ./wait-for-it.sh /app/wait-for-it.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/wait-for-it.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","-c","/app/wait-for-it.sh db:3306 -t 30 -- /app/start.sh"]
```

In my docker-compose.yml I replaced
`image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.25` with `build: .` which causes a new build from the Dockerfile in my project path.

Now the new image will be built from the prisma image and the wait-for-it.sh will be copied into the new image. Then the ENTRYPOINT is overridden and prisma will wait until the db is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing internal and external ports. Database is visible on port `3306` inside your network, so you have to wait on `db:3306` and not on `33061`.

Port exposing has no effect inside user-defined bridge network, created by default by `docker-compose`. All ports are visible to containers inside network by default. When you expose port, you make it visible **outside** network.

Also, make sure what is `ENTRYPOINT` for image `prismagraphql/prisma:1.25`. If it is not `/bin/sh -c` or other type of shell, your `command` wont get executed.

## UPD

If you get `ENTRYPOINT` in base image different from `/bin/sh -c`, you can **override** it. Supposing you have `/bin/sh -c /app/start.sh`, you could do following magic:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
...
services:
  prisma:
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "'./wait-for-it.sh db:3306 && /app/start.sh'"]
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I found out via portainer that `/bin/sh -c /app/start.sh` is the ENTRYPOINT of the image. So my command will be executed?

Comment: It depends. You will get the overall command as `/bin/sh -c /app/start.sh ./wait-for-it.sh db:33061 --`.So, depending on the content of `start.sh` - you can get your script executed or not

Comment: Ok it seems to override the entrypoint. My problem now is, that I don't know how to get the `wait-for-it.sh` to work, because I don't know how to get it into the container so it can be executed there.

Comment: Shouldn't `./wait-for-it.sh db:33061` be `./wait-for-it.sh db:3306` instead?

Comment: Sure, thank you, my bad :) That was the topic of the first half of my post)